# Evaluate String to Double (Postfix-notation)

Tags: java, postfix-notation

I wanted to create a method, that interprets this List (The method "words" splits a String into a list of words, that are seperated by \s.) in postfix-notation. This is what I got, by I am wondering if there is a shorter way to solve this, as I am repeating myself quite often there.

```
    public static double eval(String expr) {
        return eval_(new ListStack<Double>() , words(expr));
    }

    private static double eval_(Stack<Double> s, List<String> expr) {
        if (expr.isEmpty()) {
            return s.top();
        } else if (expr.head().equals("+")) {
            Double fstValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            Double sndValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            s = s.push(add.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
            return eval_(s, expr.tail());
        } else if (expr.head().equals("-")) {
            Double fstValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            Double sndValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            s = s.push(sub.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
            return eval_(s, expr.tail());
        } else if (expr.head().equals("*")) {
            Double fstValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            Double sndValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            s = s.push(mul.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
            return eval_(s, expr.tail());
        } else if (expr.head().equals("/")) {
            Double fstValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            Double sndValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            s = s.push(div.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
            return eval_(s, expr.tail());
        } else if (expr.head().equals("^")) {
            Double fstValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            Double sndValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            s = s.push(pow.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
            return eval_(s, expr.tail());
        } else if (expr.head().equals("!")) {
            Double fstValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            s = s.push(fact.apply(fstValue));
            return eval_(s, expr.tail());
        } else {
            Double value = Double.parseDouble(expr.head());
            s = s.push(value);
            return eval_(s, expr.tail());
        }
    }
```

I tried this to shorten it a little:

```
    private static double eval_(Stack<Double> s, List<String> expr) {
        Double fstValue;
        Double sndValue;
        if (expr.isEmpty()) {
            return s.top();
        } else if (!expr.isEmpty()) {
            fstValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            sndValue = s.top();
            s = s.pop();
            if (expr.head().equals("+") && !expr.isEmpty()) {
                s = s.push(add.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
                return eval_(s, expr.tail());
            } else if (expr.head().equals("-") && !expr.isEmpty()) {
                s = s.push(sub.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
                return eval_(s, expr.tail());
            } else if (expr.head().equals("*") && !expr.isEmpty()) {
                s = s.push(mul.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
                return eval_(s, expr.tail());
            } else if (expr.head().equals("/") && !expr.isEmpty()) {
                s = s.push(div.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
                return eval_(s, expr.tail());
            } else if (expr.head().equals("^") && !expr.isEmpty()) {
                s = s.push(pow.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
                return eval_(s, expr.tail());
            } else if (expr.head().equals("!") && !expr.isEmpty()) {
                s = s.push(fact.apply(fstValue));
                return eval_(s, expr.tail());
            }
            else {
                Double value = Double.parseDouble(expr.head());
                s = s.push(value);
                return eval_(s, expr.tail());
            }
        } else {
            Double value = Double.parseDouble(expr.head());
            s = s.push(value);
            return eval_(s, expr.tail());
        }
    }
```

```
Edit:
Input:
System.out.println(eval(5 6 + 8 *));
'Interpreted as (5+6) * 8 = 11 * 8'
Output: "88"
    private static final Function<Double, Function<Double, Double>> add  = x -> y -> x + y;
    private static final Function<Double, Function<Double, Double>> sub = x -> y -> x - y;
    private static final Function<Double, Function<Double, Double>> mul = x -> y -> x * y;
    private static final Function<Double, Function<Double, Double>> div = x -> y -> x / y;
    private static final Function<Double, Function<Double, Double>> pow = x -> y -> Math.pow(x,y);
    private static final Function<Double, Double> fact = Postfix::fact;


    public static double fact(double i){
        return i > 1 ? i * fact(i - 1) : 1;
    }
```

Neither its working nor is it really short. (My prof told me I could do it in one line tho).
I appreciate you helping me!

Edit 2: I tried what @Rocco answered (and simplified it using IntelliJ)

```
    private static double eval(String expr) {
        switch (expr) {
            case "+" -> s.push(add.apply(s.popTop().fst).apply(s.popTop().fst));
            case "-" -> s.push(sub.apply(s.popTop().fst).apply(s.popTop().fst));
            case "*" -> s.push(mul.apply(s.popTop().fst).apply(s.popTop().fst));
            case "/" -> s.push(div.apply(s.popTop().fst).apply(s.popTop().fst));
            case "^" -> {
                double exp = s.popTop().fst;
                s.push(Math.pow(s.popTop().fst, exp));
            }
            case "!" -> {
                s.push(fact.apply(s.popTop().fst));
            }
            default -> s.push(Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(expr)));
        }
        return s.popTop().fst;
    }
```

It always throws a "NumberFormatException". (Probably because it cant parse "+" as Double)

Comment: It would be useful to provide an example of the desired input and output

Comment: I posted a possible solution, but you should clarify some methods that you're using (sum, add, mul, div, pow), are these methods already provided as library or part of your implementation? In case provide the description and the signature. Other point 'fact ' should have a single operand but you pop two values from the stack.

Comment: I added some of the Functions, so you can see what they do. Thank you for helping me out with it!

Comment: If your stack does not behave as the standard Java stack then you should replace pop() with some corresponding code, what is popTop() in your implementation? Moreover if you get a NumberFormatException then you have a token that is neither a number nor any of the defined operator, so definitely a wrong input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your prof is kidding you, but yes, you make it shorter (not a single line, unless you just remove all LFs).

Just to explain, this is a minimal implementation of a shift-reduce parser, when you have a number just push it to the stack (shift), when an operator replace the topmost operands with the result of the operation.

Note that I'm not checking errors here, so an incorrect expression can return a wrong value.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class PostFixEprParser {
    public static double eval(String expr) {
        Stack<Double> s=new Stack<>();
        for (String token: expr.split("\\s+")) {
            switch (token) {
            case "+":
                s.push(s.pop()+s.pop());
                break;
            case "-":
                s.push(s.pop()-s.pop());
                break;
            case "*":
                s.push(s.pop()*s.pop());
                break;
            case "/":
                s.push(s.pop()/s.pop());
                break;
            case "^":
            {
                double exp=s.pop();
                s.push(Math.pow(s.pop(), exp));
            }
                break;
            case "!":
                //TODO Here define your factorial function s.push(fact(s.pop()));
                break;
            default:
                s.push(Double.valueOf(token));
            }
        }
        return s.pop();
    }
```

Comment: s.pop() returns a Stack and not single Variable (we had to implement the Stack (and List) ourselves). So I might run into problems there.

Comment: @Sentenza_IV so I asked about custom functions, since here I used the Java standard stack implementation where pop() return an element.

Comment: @Sentenza_IV Why? `s.pop()` should certainly return the value popped. Otherwise you have to write another line of code to get it: what's the point? Although those who designed the C++ STL apparently did not agree. In any case that is a constraint which is not stated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**What I did**

1. I replaced the `if`-`else` statement with `switch`-`case` (I do not have to use `break`, because I `return`.
2. I removed unnecessary `else`-statements (don't use them if you already returned in the `if`-statement).
3. I extracted a method called "evalSingle" (you have to replace ??? with whatever `add`, `sub` ... are).

**Code**

```
private static double eval_(Stack <Double> s, List <String> expr) {
    if (expr.isEmpty()) {
        return s.top();
    } else if (!expr.isEmpty()) {
        switch (expr.head()) {
            case "+":
                return evalSingle(s, expr, add);
            case "-":
                return evalSingle(s, expr, sub);
            case "*":
                return evalSingle(s, expr, mul);
            case "/":
                return evalSingle(s, expr, div);
            case "^":
                return evalSingle(s, expr, pow);
            case "!":
                return evalSingle(s, expr, fact);
        }
    }
    Double value = Double.parseDouble(expr.head());
    s = s.push(value);
    return eval_(s, expr.tail());
}

private static double evalSingle(Stack <Double> s, List <String> expr, ??? operator) {
    Double fstValue = s.top();
    s = s.pop();
    Double sndValue = s.top();
    s = s.pop();

    s = s.push(operator == fact ? operator.apply(fstValue) : operator.apply(fstValue).apply(sndValue));
    return eval_(s, expr.tail());
}
```